# Connecting to my WiFi hotspot and WiFi printer at the same time?

Tags: wireless-networking, printing

Is there a way to connect to a wireless printer, and to the Verizon MIFI hotspot at the same time?

Comment: Which OS is in question?  What have you attempted already?

Answer (score 1):

Configure the printer to connect to the MiFi.

Radios can't be on two channels at once. Even if you arranged for the MiFi and the printer to be on the same channel, making one client device join more than one network simultaneously is not widely supported, and not widely attempted, because it can be very fiddly.